# Word to group some interrelated computer programs

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, names, technical

I am looking for a word to group some interrelated computer programs, to name my github repository

The group includes (or github repo) these programs:

**dwm** — a window manager for unix like operating systems

**st** — a terminal emulator

**dmemu** — a program launcher

**dwmblocks** — a status monitor

First I named it *dwmmates*, then changed it to *dwmset*—sounds like set of the specific program dwm of different versions, that's why I want to change it.

I want something which connect them all.

I have a word in mind—constellation but it's too long so short it to con? dwmcon?

Comment: This is a naming request and will be highly opinion-based and thus off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A group of related programs is sometimes called a **suite**.  One definition in the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suite) dictionary is:

> a set of computer programs designed to work together and usually sold as a single unit

Other words you didn’t mention include **collection**, **group** and **package** (especially if they have the same installer).